# SQL GROUP BY strange behavior

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have some query to DB where I use group by date.
When I run query without group by I have normal result with normal date, but when I use group by I have column with 1970-01-01 date.

Perhaps someone means what is the problem? Why can't I see this date 1970-01-01
when I run a query without the group by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your query. CH by default does not use Nulls.

1970-01-01 -- is default value for Date type , a substitute for Null.

You can write a query which produces these values as a result of group by ROLLUP/CUBE.